# Why is this a comment, and is not an answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was curious to know why [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/51680/3443) was deleted and converted to [this comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/why-is-cheque-cashing-a-legitimate-business#comment79414_51677)?

I don't think that it should have been converted.

- I think *it is an answer* i.e. that it answers the question; specifically it says that answers include:

  1. To get cash when banks are closed
  2. To avoid creditors

  I admit it's based on personal experience however that (i.e. experience) [is *supposed* to be](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) an attribute of an answer, to a subjective question such as "why do people...?" and "who uses...?".

  > The folks at Moms4mom owned up to the subjective issue and came up with a set of principles to create useful subjective discussions on parenting: the Back It Up! Principle. Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either:
  >
  > - Something that happened to you **personally**
  > - Something you can **back up** with a reference
- Furthermore *it is not a comment* on the question: e.g. not a request that the question be clarified.

  Some SE sites specifically don't want 'pseudo-answers' being posted as a comment, when they ought to be posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the question is "Why is “cheque cashing” a legitimate business?"

and you wrote a personal story (not bad, in and of itself) about why that concerned your boss. In my opinion, and that of the flagger, it didn't explain why, today, check cashing is a large, legitimate business.

Comment: So I take the complaint is that the data is too old, and furthermore doesn't explain the size of the industry. Well, thank you for your explanation, I'll delete the comment then as well. You should edit the last paragraph of [NuWin's answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/51684/3443).

Comment: I've raised the issue to the other mods as well. And invited them to reopen your answer if they wish. In my opinion, it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think I flagged that post as

> **not an answer**
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to
>   answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another
>   question, or deleted altogether.  and suggested that it was a comment
>   not an answer.

It did talk about a personal experience, which is good; but then used phrases such as:

- I forget why,
- maybe ... or something.

The second part of the post tried to add more detail, but were just more guesses.

The question wanted to know: how they could survive as a business, isn't that business risky due to bounced checks, and why do people use them?

The post only attempted to answer the last one and then even did that poorly. I thought that it essentially boiled down to "I used one once 20+ years ago but I don't remember why."

Comment: I'm pretty sure now I did it because it was the weekend: and so I could edit it (if it were an answer, I can't edit an old comment) to tighten that up. I thought the second part of it (trying to avoid declaring income) was interesting too (more interesting than the first). Also, whether or not it's acceptable as an answer, I doubt whether it ought to be posted as a comment instead; if it's not answer perhaps it should be deleted entirely.